# How to catch error while installing software using Process.Start()

Tags: c#, console-application

I am installing some windows update via c# code block using following code.

```
Process myProcess = new Process();

myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DownloadedPath"];
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
myProcess.Start(); 

myProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Now i am afraid that if the update which is there in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DownloadedPath"] path will install properly or not.

If this update threw any exception while installing software how can i handle it in c#?

Comment: Guys I want to catch internal exception occurring in myProcess.Start() command.

Comment: So then surround that line in a try catch block

Answer (score 1):

The exception in your app (downloadpath) should be handled gracefully with an exit code. 
myProcess can then look at the exit code and decide what to do in case of exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle any exceptions by containing your code in a try-catch block.
You would include any code that might throw an exception in the try statement and then any code you want to handle the exception in the catch statement.

Your code would look like this:

```
try
{
    //Start your process here
}
catch (System.Exception e)
{
    //Anything you want to do to handle any exception thrown
}
```

More information about the try catch block can be found here:

[Try-Catch C# MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx)